# Spring & Docker: RMI Hostname resolved to 0.0.0.0 and not to its expected IP address

Tags: java, spring, docker, docker-compose, rmi

I am currently working on a project that associates Docker and Spring programs with an RMI service, and I can't find a way to resolve my problem.

I'm trying to deploy two Spring programs into two distinct containers, through a `docker-compose.yml` file. The first one exposes an RMI interface at address `0.0.0.0` (everything), and on a specific port (which is EXPOSEd as well in the Docker file). And the second one is just an RMI client using the remote interface.

To access the container that exposes the RMI service from the other, I gave it an alias through the `links` parameter in the Compose file, like this :

```
services:
  rmi-service:
    ...

  rmi-client:
    ...
    links:
      - rmi-service:rmihost
```

When I start my containers with `docker-compose up -d`, if I execute the command `ping rmihost` from the second container, it works well. But when I try to start my Spring RMI client, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'my.rmi.client' defined in class path resource [META-INF/rmi-client-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.remoting.RemoteConnectFailureException: Could not connect to remote service [rmi://rmihost:11199/businessService]; nested exception is
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 0.0.0.0
```

I can't figure out why it doesn't translate the hostname into the correct IP address, while I'm able to `ping` it. I tried adding the `rmihost` in the `/etc/hosts` file, but it doesn't change anything, it always gives the same error.

Any help or suggestion on this problem will be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**EDIT** Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file :

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  rmi-service:
    restart: always
    tty: true
    build: ./rmi-service/
    image: rmi-service
    container_name: rmi-service
    expose:
      - "11199"

  rmi-client:
    restart: always
    tty: true
    build: ./rmi-client/
    image: rmi-client
    container_name: rmi-client
    depends_on:
      - rmi-service
    links:
      - rmi-service:rmihost
```

Comment: Could you please post your entire compose file? that makes it easier to find possible problems.

Comment: Added `docker-compose.yml` file